# Undefined Index with existing variables

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I know that with this error the variable doesn't exist in the array. Weirdly when I check the array, it does exists...... Am I blind? Am I missing something?

**Undefined index: uuid on line 141**

```
foreach($orderDetails->line_items as $orderLineItem) {

   foreach($returnLineItems as $itemKey => $value){

       if($orderLineItem->uuid == $returnLineItems[$itemKey]['uuid']) { //Line 141
       }
   }
}
```

Although this is an object:

```
dd($orderLineItem->uuid) => 236cb65b-a602-4422-a11a-803bd7dbf05d
```

The array:

```
dd($returnLineItems[$itemKey]['uuid'] => 236cb65b-a602-4422-a11a-803bd7dbf05d
```

Upon Comment request the DD of the entire [image]

Comment: Please post a dump of the actual array `$returnLineItems` It's hard to know what's wrong if we have no clue what the data actually looks like.

Comment: You use `dd()` when you dump inside a foreach, so you dump and stop the code. so the first item will have a 'uuid', one of the following iterations it wil be missing.

Comment: you are getting the error on one of the entrie in `$returnLineItems[$itemKey]` which doesnt have `uuid` index. the `dd($returnLineItems[$itemKey]['uuid'])` will return only the first entry. Do a `dd($returnLineItems)` you will see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after two hours I found it...

I was regenerating $returnLineItems in the foreach loop, causing the array to miss UUID.

Thanks for helping all!